# Using RDP to connect to an Ubuntu 22.04 multipass desktop VM with Wayland

Tags: remote-desktop, wayland, rdp, multipass

I currently have a `multipass` VM setup for `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` with desktop installed. I'm accessing this right now via `xrdp` and `Microsoft-Remote-Desktop` client on macOS M1.

I would like to access this the same way, but instead have the VM use `wayland`.
Right now, it's using `x11` because the client is connecting to the `xrdp` server on the VM. How can my setup be configured to use `wayland` instead?

I read that using `gnome-remote-desktop` should allow for `wayland`, but I cannot get that to work unless `xrdp` is installed.